# t.test on data formatted for boxplot

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data formatted in this way. It says that my algorithm had result 1 on input1 and the other had result 0.6 on input1.

```
Label input1 input2
Mine  1       0.9
Mine  0.9     0.7
Mine  0.5     0.2
Other 0.6     0.7
Other 0.8     0.3
Other 0.3     0.1
```

After searching a lot on the internet, I succeeded to plot a nice boxplot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(lattice)
dataset <- read.table("sample.txt", header=TRUE, sep="", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
dat.m <- melt(dataset,id.vars='Label')
bwplot(value~Label | paste0(variable), data=dat.m,   main="Mine vs Other", layout=c(2,1), par.settings = list(box.rectangle = list(fill= rep(c('blue','red'),2))))
```

How can I perform a paired t.test now comparing `Mine` vs `Other`?

I guess the whole problem is due to this new format and `melt` which I am not used to. The way I used to do before was putting all `Mine` in one colunm and all the `Other` in another column and call it like this:

`t.test(dataset$Mine,dataset$Other,paired=T)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two options of doing it:

```
mine = subset(dataset, dataset$Label=="Mine")
other = subset(dataset, dataset$Label=="Other")
t.test(mine,other)
```

or more easily as someone pointed out:

```
t.test(value ~ Label, data = dat.m)
```